# How can I use a composer generated bin script with a different php binary?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm using a PHP library that has a cli script file with shebang on top:

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
```

This file is meant to be used by cli so it's defined as a `bin` on composer config [as expected](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/vendor-binaries.md#what-happens-when-composer-is-run-on-a-composer-json-that-has-dependencies-with-vendor-binaries-listed-).

When I do a `composer install`, the composer generates a link to this file on `vendor/bin` folder like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

dir=$(d=${0%[/\\]*}; cd "$d" > /dev/null; cd "../lib-owner/lib" && pwd)

dir=$(echo $dir | sed 's/ /\ /g')
"${dir}/lib" "$@"
```

The problem is that with this setup, every call to `vendor/bin/the-library` is just forwarded to the php script file, and it lets the shebang resolve the PHP version, but I need this script to be called **with a specific php binary.**

I can resolve it by calling the script file directly: `php73 /vendor/lib-owner/lib/lib/the-script`.

Or by cloning the script into my root folder and calling it there in the place of the vendor: `php73 the-script`.

The problem is that both ways has some drawbacks and I would prefer something more stable and less hacky.

Is there anyway?

Comment: How about something like `env PATH="/path/to/your/php/binary:$PATH" vendor/bin/the-library`?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work :(

I tested using this docker image with multiple PHP versions: https://blog.eriksen.com.br/en/docker-image-multi-version-php-development .

And executed: `env PATH="/opt/phpenv/versions/5.4/bin/php:$PATH" vendor/bin/crunz` but the result is of the PHP 5.6 version that is the default.

Comment: That's surprising, because `env` should find the first `php` executable in the PATH. Are you sure you should add `/php` before `:$PATH`? Isn't it the binary itself?

Comment: Omg, you're right!
I tried `env PATH="/opt/phpenv/versions/5.4/bin:$PATH" vendor/bin/crunz` and know it worked. Nice solution, thank you!

Comment: Nice! I'll add it as an answer so it can maybe help people in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
env PATH="/path/to/folder/where/desired/php/resides:$PATH" vendor/bin/the-library
```

What it does is alter the `PATH` environment variable just for the duration of that command, by prepending the path to the desired PHP interpreter.

This way, `/usr/bin/env` will use that PHP version instead of the default one (and the `PATH` environment variable will revert back to its previous value as soon as the script is finished).